# После установки обновлений на Windows-10 иногда не подключается вай-фай

Tags: windows, windows-10

Добрый день.

Введение в проблему:

Есть ноутбук ACER Pentium четырехядерный довольно новый (CPU N3540 покупал полтора года назад). На нем стояла Windows-8 после покупки она проапгрейдилась до Windows-10-64 Home Edition. Что важно для сюжета, в сеть я выхожу по вай-фаю. Windows-10-64 периодически качает обновления. Последние три обновления установлены 14.06.2017 и называются:

1. Накопительное обновление для Windows 10 Version 1703 для систем на базе процессоров x64, 2017 06 (KB4022725)
2. Обновление системы безопасности для Adobe Flash Player for Windows 10 Version 1703 для систем на базе процессоров x64 (KB4022730), 06.2017
3. Обновление для Windows 10 Version 1703 для систем на базе процессоров x64 (KB4022405), 06.2017

После установки этих обновлений проявилась неприятная особенность: примерно в половине случаев после включения машины вай-фай не подключается автоматически, хотя роутер исправен и машина исправна. Приходится вручную подключать вай-фай. Проблема не то чтобы критична, но немного надоедает. Лезу в сеть, отклика нет. Начинаю судорожно трясти машину и нажимать разные кнопки а потом вспоминаю что вай-фай не всегда подключился автоматически. Включаю вай-фай вручную, все работает но уровень сервиса уже не торт. До установки упомянутых обновлений такого никогда не наблюдалось. Повторю, что такое случается только примерно в половине случаев включения, а в другой половине случаев вай-фай нормально подключается автоматом.

Вопросы:

1. Что делать? Хочу чтобы вай-фай ВСЕГДА подключался автоматом как и раньше.
2. Кто виноват?

Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В настройках - Сеть и интернет - Wi-Fi стоит галочка подключаться автоматически у вашей сети Wifi ? В свойствах беспроводной сети, в изменении параметров адаптера, во вкладке "Подключения" стоит галочка подключаться к сети автоматически?

Так же попробуйте в Системных параметрах электропитания снять галочку "Быстрый старт" и проверьте после перезагрузки своего PC/Ноутбука

Comment: 1. в настройка сети стоит галочка "подключаться автоматически" <br/> 2. в параметрах адаптера такой галочки нет <br/> 3. в параметрах электропитания нет галочки "быстрый старт"

Comment: @pepsicoca1 зайдите в Центр управления сетями и общим доступом, и справа будет беспроводная сеть. Зайдите в свойства беспроводной сети и проверьте галочку. И про электропитание проверьте!

Comment: Галочку "Быстрый запуск" я нашел и снял. Теперь погляжу что получится. Называется она "Быстрый запуск" а не "Быстрый старт".

Comment: @pepsicoca1 жду вашего ответа!

Comment: Но в параметрах адаптера Wi-Fi я не нашел галочку "подключаться автоматически".

Comment: @pepsicoca1 Центр управления сетями и общим доступом, справа будет написано "Беспроводная сеть ( имя сети )" После нажатия, будет  "Состояние - Беспроводная сеть" окно, далее будет первые две кнопки, "Сведения" и "Свойства беспроводной сети" - Заходим в свойства беспроводной сети и смотрим галочку автоматического подключения

Comment: В свойствах беспроводной сети галочка "подключаться автоматически" стоит и всегда стояла. Но это не свойства адаптера Wi-Fi.  В свойствах адаптера Wi-Fi галочки "подключаться автоматически" нет.

Comment: Похоже дело было в галочке "быстрый запуск". Во всяком случае за 6 дней с тех пор как я снял эту галочку wi-fi все время включался автоматически и ни разу не было такого, чтобы wi-fi не включился при включении компьютера. Спасибо.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 Не за что.